# Configuring Private Endpoints and NAT Gateway for Static Outbound IP in App Service

Tags: azure, terraform

I'm working on a personal project which includes 2x ASP.NET Core Web APIs, hosted as Linux web apps. In the near future, I plan to add a React frontend as another Linux web app. The infrastructure design involves configuring Application Insights for both backend web apps, utilizing Azure Key Vault, and integrating a shared SQL database across the applications. I'm trying to keep the resources in a private network (not exposed to the Internet), and also use NAT gateway to provide a static outbound IP address for one of both APIs which connects to a 3rd party API and that API requires a specific static outbound IP address that can be whitelisted in their API configuration.

I've come across various [approaches](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/scripts/terraform-secure-backend-frontend) that involve using private endpoints, network security groups to manage traffic access, and user-defined routes to channel the traffic. However, I find myself uncertain whether these methods can be coherently integrated with my NAT Gateway implementation, especially regarding the static outbound IP address.

Given this context, I have a couple of questions that I'd appreciate guidance on:

1. How can I align the private endpoints for Application Insights, Key Vault, and SQL database with my existing NAT Gateway implementation for a static outbound IP address? What would be the specific implementation?
2. Is there anything absent in my code that could further enhance the security or functionality of the resources, taking into consideration my unique requirements?

Here's the Terraform code that represents the current state of my setup:

```
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "rg" {
  name     = "${local.basename}-rg"
  location = "East US"
}

resource "azurerm_service_plan" "asp" {
  name                = "${local.basename}-asp"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
  os_type             = "Linux"
  sku_name            = "S1"
}

resource "azurerm_linux_web_app" "app" {
  name                = "${local.basename}-app"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
  service_plan_id     = azurerm_service_plan.asp.id

  site_config {
    vnet_route_all_enabled = true # WEBSITE_VNET_ROUTE_ALL
  }

  identity {
    type = "SystemAssigned"
  }
}

resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "vnet" {
  name                = "${local.basename}-vnet"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
  address_space       = ["10.0.0.0/16"]
}

resource "azurerm_subnet" "snet" {
  name                 = "${local.basename}-linuxapp-snet"
  resource_group_name  = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.vnet.name
  address_prefixes     = ["10.0.1.0/24"]

  delegation {
    name = "delegation"

    service_delegation {
      name    = "Microsoft.Web/serverFarms"
      actions = ["Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets/action"]
    }
  }
}

resource "azurerm_subnet_nat_gateway_association" "example" {
  subnet_id      = azurerm_subnet.snet.id
  nat_gateway_id = azurerm_nat_gateway.ng.id
}

resource "azurerm_public_ip" "pip" {
  name                = "${local.basename}-pip"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
  allocation_method   = "Static"
  sku                 = "Standard"
  zones               = ["1"]
}

resource "azurerm_nat_gateway" "ng" {
  name                    = "${local.basename}-ng"
  resource_group_name     = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  location                = azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
  sku_name                = "Standard"
  idle_timeout_in_minutes = 10
  zones                   = ["1"]
}

resource "azurerm_nat_gateway_public_ip_association" "association" {
  nat_gateway_id       = azurerm_nat_gateway.ng.id
  public_ip_address_id = azurerm_public_ip.pip.id
}

resource "azurerm_app_service_virtual_network_swift_connection" "example" {
  app_service_id = azurerm_linux_web_app.app.id
  subnet_id      = azurerm_subnet.snet.id
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assign private endpoints for azure services like `Application Insights`, `Key Vault`, and `SQL Database` with existing `NAT Gateway` implementation for a static outbound IP address involves creating the private endpoints within the same subnet that is associated with the NAT Gateway.

For each service `(Application Insights, Key Vault, and SQL Database)`, created a private endpoint and associate it with the subnet that is already associated with the `NAT Gateway`.

> 1.How can I align the private endpoints for Application Insights, Key Vault, and SQL database with my existing NAT Gateway implementation

Here is the terraform code for align the private endpoints for `Application Insights, Key Vault, and SQL database` with my existing `NAT Gateway`

```
provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
}

#Application Insights Private Endpoint
data "azurerm_application_insights" "example"{
  name                = "venkattest"
  resource_group_name = "web-app-rg"
}

data "azurerm_subnet" "example" {
  name                 = "samplesubnet"
  virtual_network_name = "vnet"
  resource_group_name  = "web-app-rg"
}
data "azurerm_key_vault" "example" {
  name                = "venkattest"
  resource_group_name = "web-app-rg"
}
data "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
  name = "web-app-rg"
}
#Key Vault Private Endpoint
resource "azurerm_private_endpoint" "pe_kv" {
  name                = "samplevault"
  location            = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  subnet_id           = data.azurerm_subnet.example.id

  private_service_connection {
    name                           = "ssampletest"
    private_connection_resource_id = data.azurerm_key_vault.example.id
    is_manual_connection           = false
    subresource_names = ["Vault"]
  }
}

#SQL Database with Private Endpoint creation
resource "azurerm_mssql_server" "example" {
  name                         = "mssqlservertest1"
  resource_group_name          = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  location                     = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  version                      = "12.0"
  administrator_login          = "mradministrator"
  administrator_login_password = "thisIsDog11"

  tags = {
    environment = "production"
  }
}
resource "azurerm_private_endpoint" "example" {
  name                = "webapp-endpoint"
  location            = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  subnet_id           = data.azurerm_subnet.example.id

  private_service_connection {
    name                           = "sample-privateserviceconnection"
    private_connection_resource_id = azurerm_mssql_server.example.id
    subresource_names              = [ "mysqlServer" ]
    is_manual_connection           = false
  }
}

#Application Insights Private Endpoint

resource "azurerm_monitor_private_link_scope" "amplsMain" {
  name                = "sampletest2"
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
}
resource "azurerm_monitor_private_link_scoped_service" "example" {
  name                = "example-amplsservice1"
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  scope_name          = azurerm_monitor_private_link_scope.amplsMain.name
  linked_resource_id  = data.azurerm_application_insights.example.id
  depends_on = [ azurerm_monitor_private_link_scope.amplsMain ]
}

resource "azurerm_private_endpoint" "amplsMainPrivateEndpoint" {
  name = "samplemonitor"
  location = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  subnet_id = data.azurerm_subnet.example.id
  private_service_connection {
    name = "sampleendpoint"
    private_connection_resource_id = azurerm_monitor_private_link_scope.amplsMain.id
    is_manual_connection = false
    subresource_names = ["azuremonitor"]
  }
}
```

> Note: If you delegate the subnet to the web app, it won't be available for use by other resources

**Terraform apply:**

[image]

Make sure that the `subnet_id` provided for each private endpoint (`azurerm_private_endpoint`) is the same subnet that is associated with existing `NAT Gateway`.

> 2. Is there anything absent in my code that could further enhance the security or functionality of the resources, taking into consideration
>    my unique requirements?

Here is the updated code with enhancements for security and functionality.

```
provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
}
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "rg" {
  name     = "web-app-rg"
  location = "East US"
}
resource "azurerm_service_plan" "asp" {
  name                = "web-app-asp"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
  os_type             = "Linux"
  sku_name            = "S1"
  depends_on = [ azurerm_resource_group.rg ]
}

resource "azurerm_linux_web_app" "app" {
  name                = "sample-web-app"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
  service_plan_id     = azurerm_service_plan.asp.id

  site_config {
    vnet_route_all_enabled = true 
  }

  identity {
    type = "SystemAssigned"
  }
  depends_on = [ azurerm_service_plan.asp ]
}

resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "vnet" {
  name                = "web-app-vnet"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
  address_space       = ["10.0.0.0/16"]
depends_on = [ azurerm_linux_web_app.app ]
}

resource "azurerm_subnet" "snet" {
  name                 = "web-linuxapp-snet"
  resource_group_name  = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.vnet.name
  address_prefixes     = ["10.0.1.0/24"]
 depends_on = [ azurerm_virtual_network.vnet ]
}

resource "azurerm_subnet_nat_gateway_association" "example" {
  subnet_id      = azurerm_subnet.snet.id
  nat_gateway_id = azurerm_nat_gateway.ng.id
 depends_on = [ azurerm_subnet.snet ]
}

resource "azurerm_public_ip" "pip" {
  name                = "web-app-pip"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
  allocation_method   = "Static"
  sku                 = "Standard"
  zones               = ["1"]
  depends_on = [ azurerm_subnet_nat_gateway_association.example ]
}

resource "azurerm_nat_gateway" "ng" {
  name                    = "web-app-ng"
  resource_group_name     = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  location                = azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
  sku_name                = "Standard"
  idle_timeout_in_minutes = 10
  zones                   = ["1"]
}

resource "azurerm_nat_gateway_public_ip_association" "association" {
  nat_gateway_id       = azurerm_nat_gateway.ng.id
  public_ip_address_id = azurerm_public_ip.pip.id
}

resource "azurerm_app_service_virtual_network_swift_connection" "example" {
  app_service_id = azurerm_linux_web_app.app.id
  subnet_id      = azurerm_subnet.snet.id
}

# Enhancements for security and functionality

# Add Network Security Group to the subnet
resource "azurerm_network_security_group" "subnet_nsg" {
  name                = "web-subnet-nsg"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
}

resource "azurerm_network_security_rule" "allow_http" {
  name                        = "AllowHTTP"
  priority                    = 100
  direction                   = "Inbound"
  access                      = "Allow"
  protocol                    = "Tcp"
  source_port_range           = "*"
  destination_port_range      = "80"
  source_address_prefix       = "*"
  destination_address_prefix  = "*"
  resource_group_name         = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  network_security_group_name = azurerm_network_security_group.subnet_nsg.name
}

resource "azurerm_network_security_rule" "allow_https" {
  name                        = "AllowHTTPS"
  priority                    = 101
  direction                   = "Inbound"
  access                      = "Allow"
  protocol                    = "Tcp"
  source_port_range           = "*"
  destination_port_range      = "443"
  source_address_prefix       = "*"
  destination_address_prefix  = "*"
  resource_group_name         = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  network_security_group_name = azurerm_network_security_group.subnet_nsg.name
}
#Associate the NSG with the subnet
resource "azurerm_subnet_network_security_group_association" "example" {
  subnet_id                 = azurerm_subnet.snet.id
  network_security_group_id = azurerm_network_security_group.subnet_nsg.id
}
```

**Terraform apply:**

[image]

The added code for `Network Security Groups`  and rules to enhance security to the resources. It provides basic inbound traffic control for your web app subnet by allowing HTTP and HTTPS traffic. This helps in securing the communication channels and controlling access to your resources.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! You're right, I tried the same on a delegated subnet, but it didn't work out. What's the purpose of that delegation? And I wonder if I really need it? Because if you look at Microsoft's example, they have two subnets, one delegated and another one non-delegated: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/scripts/terraform-secure-backend-frontend. In addition, here is what I've been following for the NAT gateway implementation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/networking/nat-gateway-integration

Comment: The purpose of subnet delegation is to allow certain Azure services to extend their functionality into your virtual network. When you delegate a subnet to a service, you are granting that service permission to provision certain resources within that subnet. This can enhance the capabilities of the services and provide them with direct network access to the delegated subnet.

Comment: @VenkatV thanks for the explanation! In other words, I dont have to worry that it's not longer delegated.